# How to debug a web service in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have to make some changes to a Web Service which is currently in production.

There is a project (a class library) called Accounts.WebServer which is a container project, it's Global.asax initializes a WCF service as an instance of the web service class.

My question is how can I run the web service (container project or project containing the web service) locally? I try and run the container project through VS2015 and I get a lot of IIS errors, one I fixed by adding

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
```

to the web.config

But I am still unable to get the web service to run. Once it is running I should be able to see a page which lists the operations exposed, and see sample data to pass to the operations.

Comment: Does it have a .asmx or .svc file in the project?

Comment: Neither - both projects are a class library and the end result is DLL.

Comment: where do you host these services on your local machine